# Navbar not filling width of page when reduced to mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[**Screenshot of problem here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndV8b.png)This is my first post to stackoverflow so go easy on me if I am not doing something right haha.

I'm working on my project for a course I am doing. It's with Bootstrap 4 and the issue I am having is the navbar when being resized starts to lose it's full width. My guess is the content beneath it was causing this but I am not sure how I go about fixing it.

I really would appreciate any guidance here as it's been driving me mental and I know it's possibly somthing so easy but I can't spot what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance look forward to chatting.

Mike

```css
html body {
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    background-color: #181a3d;
}

/*---------------------Navbar Section---------------------------------------*/
#navbar-color {
    background-color: #1e203f!important;
    border: solid #6fc4a2;
}

.nav-link {
    display: block;
    padding: .25rem 1.5rem!important;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-link-color {
    color: white!important;
}

.nav-link-color:hover {
    color: #6fc4a2!important;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    color: #f8f9fa;
    border-color: rgb(111 196 162);
    background-color: rgb(111 196 162);
}

.nav-img {
    border: groove #6fc4a2;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.sign-btn {
    border: groove #6fc4a2;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    background-color: #1e203f;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.sign-btn:hover {
    color: #6fc4a2;
}

p.nav-link-color {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

/*------------------CSS styling for the main page Box 1 and Box 2---------------------------*/

#box-1 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    border: solid transparent!important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    border-radius: 35px;
    background-color: #1e203f;
}

#box-2 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    border: solid transparent!important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    border-radius: 35px;
    background-color: #1e203f;
}

.fa, .fas:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: 3s;
}

.h2, h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem!important;
}

.h2-mem {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.p-mem {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.h2-app {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.p-app {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.hr-mem {
    background-color: #6fc4a2;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.hr-p {
    background-color: #6fc4a2;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

/*----------------------Carousel Styling---------------------------------------------*/
.carousel {
    margin: 30px 30px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    border: solid transparent!important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    border-radius: 35px;
    background-color: #1e203f;
    color: white;
  
}

#client-testimonial-carousel {
    min-height: 300px!important;
    margin: 5px 0 10px!important;
    padding-top: 45px!important;
    border: solid transparent!important;
}

.blockquote-footer {
    background-color: #1e203f;
    border: solid transparent!important;
    /* border-width: 1px; */
}

/*---------------------Navbar Dropdown Menu-----------------------------------*/
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 10rem;
    padding: .5rem 0;
    margin: .125rem 0 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #1e203f!important;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px groove #6fc4a2!important;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover {
    color: #6fc4a2!important;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #1e203f!important;
}

/*---------------------Footer Section---------------------------------------*/
footer {
    background-color: #1e203f;
    border: solid #6fc4a2;
}

.social-networks{
  text-align: center;
  
}

.social-networks li{
  display:inline;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.social-networks i {
    margin: 1%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: white;
    
}

.social-networks i:hover {
    margin: 1%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #6fc4a2;
    transform: scale(1.5);
    
}

#bf-logo {
    background-color: #181a3d;
    text-align: center!important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 40px;
}

.bf-brand {
    border: groove #6fc4a2;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

img.bf-brand:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5)!important;
    transition: 5s;
}

/*--------------------Home page boxes------------------------*/

#box-1 {    
    margin-top: 40px;
    border: solid black;
}


#box-2 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    border: solid black;
}

.home-testimonial {
    border: solid black;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.carousel {
    margin: 30px 30px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    border: solid   black;
}

#client-testimonial-carousel {
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: 30px 0 10px;
}


/*-----------------------------------Modal Header------------------------------*/
.modal-header {
    background-color: #181a3d;
    color: #6fc4a2;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 20px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%)!important;
}

.modal-title {
    text-align: center!important;
}

.close {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: white!important;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    opacity: 10!important;
}

.close:hover {
    color: #6fc4a2!important;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #6fc4a2!important;
    opacity: 10!important;
}

/*-----------------------------------Modal body------------------------------*/

.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #181a3d;
    color: #6fc4a2;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%)!important;    
}

.form-text {
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.btn-success {
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px!important;
    background-color: #6fc4a2!important;
    border-color: #6fc4a2!important;
}

.btn-success:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6fc4a2!important;
    border-color: #6fc4a2!important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

/*-------------------------------------------Bruna Page-----------------------------------*/

#bruna-image {
    border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
}

.img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #181a3d!important;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 50px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    border-radius: 30px !important;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    width: 330px!important;
}

div.card-info {
    background-color: #181a3d!important;
    border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
}

.bf-card-details {
    color: #6fc4a2!important;
}

.bf-card-job {
    color: #6fc4a2!important;
}

.card-about {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #181a3d;
    background-clip: border-box;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 50px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    border-radius: 30px!important;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 782px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bruna Fernandes Fisioteropia | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bree+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-sm" id="navbar-color">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="assets/images/bf-logo (1).png" height="60" width="60" class="nav-img" alt=""></a>
        <!----ml-auto will push this button to the right------data toggle tells Bootstrap that it will be used as a trigger for a collapsable element on the page------------->
        <!----data-target is the ID of the collapsible element-----aria = accessible rich internet applications provides accessibility options to screen readers----->
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target ="#navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <!-----inside the span we create a class that gives us the icon, our burger button----->
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">

        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link nav-link-color" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                         
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle nav-link-color" href="services.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link-color" href="fisio.html">Fisioteropia & Pilates</a>  
                            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link-color" href="appointments.html"> Appointments</a> 
                        </div>
                </li>
            
            <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link nav-link-color" href="members.html">Members</a></li>

               <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle nav-link-color" href="contact.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-link-color" href="contact.html">Contact</a> 
                    </div>
                </li>            

            
            <!---Will only display on a mob device with "d-block + d-sm-none--->
            <li class="nav-item mr-auto d-block d-sm-none"> <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal" class="sign-btn"><p class="nav-link-color" class="sign-btn">Sign In / Sign Up</p></button></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block">
            <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal" class="sign-btn">Sign In / Sign Up</button>
        </div>    
    </nav>

         <!-----Modal dialogue goes here because it captures the entire screen so it needs to be a top-level element in the body---->
 <!-----A modal is described as being an island of content that sits in the middle of the page. The modal is hidden by default----->   
 <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="signUpModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Sign Up to BF Fisioteropia!</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
                            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="repeatPassword">Repeat Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="repeatPassword" placeholder="Repeat Password" required>
                        </div>
                        
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

            <main class="container-fluid">
                
                <section class="bruna-page">
                        <div class="row justify-content-around">
                            
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"class="bruna-box-1">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img src="assets/images/bruna_professional_resized.jpg" id="bruna-image" alt="Image of Bruna Fernandes">
                                    <div class="card-info">
                                        <h4 class="text-center mt-3 bf-card-details" ><b>Bruna Fernandes</b></h4>
                                        <p class="text-center bf-card-details">Physiotherapist</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" class="bruna-box-2">
                                        <div class="card-about">
                                        <h2 class="text-center mt-4">About Bruna</h2>
                                        <hr id="hr-about">
                                        <p class="text-center mt-4 mr-5 ml-5">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                                            Voluptatem eaque, saepe cumque labore asperiores accusamus quae officiis quidem. 
                                            Iusto porr o quasi placeat, natus enim rem explicabo alias quibusdam expedita provident.
                                            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium magni est optio? 
                                            Voluptates hic animi omnis sint iure quis! 
                                            Illum quod ex aperiam animi facere nobis mollitia aut dignissimos dolorum.
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                                            Voluptatem eaque, saepe cumque labore asperiores accusamus quae officiis quidem. 
                                            Iusto porr o quasi placeat, natus enim rem explicabo alias quibusdam expedita provident.
                                            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium magni est optio? 
                                            Voluptates hic animi omnis sint iure quis! 
                                            Illum quod ex aperiam animi facere nobis mollitia aut dignissimos dolorum.
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                                            Voluptatem eaque, saepe cumque labore asperiores accusamus quae officiis quidem. 
                                            </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" class="bruna-box-3">
                                Bruna-box-3
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </section>
            </main>


<footer class="footer fixed container-fluid">
      <ul class="social-networks">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i> </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i> </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i> </a>
                </li>
            </ul> 
</footer>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to be working fine to me.

Comment: Really? I test on developer tools on different iphone frames and it doesn't scale correctly..

Comment: I've attached screenshot of the problem at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because your `.card-about` width is wider than your viewport.

Try using `max-width` instead so. I changed your `height` into `auto` so the content wont overflow when the height become bigger.

```css
html body {
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    background-color: #181a3d;
}

/*---------------------Navbar Section---------------------------------------*/
#navbar-color {
    background-color: #1e203f!important;
    border: solid #6fc4a2;
}

.nav-link {
    display: block;
    padding: .25rem 1.5rem!important;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-link-color {
    color: white!important;
}

.nav-link-color:hover {
    color: #6fc4a2!important;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    color: #f8f9fa;
    border-color: rgb(111 196 162);
    background-color: rgb(111 196 162);
}

.nav-img {
    border: groove #6fc4a2;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.sign-btn {
    border: groove #6fc4a2;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    background-color: #1e203f;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.sign-btn:hover {
    color: #6fc4a2;
}

p.nav-link-color {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

/*------------------CSS styling for the main page Box 1 and Box 2---------------------------*/

#box-1 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    border: solid transparent!important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    border-radius: 35px;
    background-color: #1e203f;
}

#box-2 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    border: solid transparent!important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    border-radius: 35px;
    background-color: #1e203f;
}

.fa, .fas:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: 3s;
}

.h2, h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem!important;
}

.h2-mem {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.p-mem {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.h2-app {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.p-app {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.hr-mem {
    background-color: #6fc4a2;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

.hr-p {
    background-color: #6fc4a2;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

/*----------------------Carousel Styling---------------------------------------------*/
.carousel {
    margin: 30px 30px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    border: solid transparent!important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    border-radius: 35px;
    background-color: #1e203f;
    color: white;
  
}

#client-testimonial-carousel {
    min-height: 300px!important;
    margin: 5px 0 10px!important;
    padding-top: 45px!important;
    border: solid transparent!important;
}

.blockquote-footer {
    background-color: #1e203f;
    border: solid transparent!important;
    /* border-width: 1px; */
}

/*---------------------Navbar Dropdown Menu-----------------------------------*/
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 10rem;
    padding: .5rem 0;
    margin: .125rem 0 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #1e203f!important;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px groove #6fc4a2!important;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover {
    color: #6fc4a2!important;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #1e203f!important;
}

/*---------------------Footer Section---------------------------------------*/
footer {
    background-color: #1e203f;
    border: solid #6fc4a2;
}

.social-networks{
  text-align: center;
  
}

.social-networks li{
  display:inline;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.social-networks i {
    margin: 1%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: white;
    
}

.social-networks i:hover {
    margin: 1%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #6fc4a2;
    transform: scale(1.5);
    
}

#bf-logo {
    background-color: #181a3d;
    text-align: center!important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 40px;
}

.bf-brand {
    border: groove #6fc4a2;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

img.bf-brand:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5)!important;
    transition: 5s;
}

/*--------------------Home page boxes------------------------*/

#box-1 {    
    margin-top: 40px;
    border: solid black;
}


#box-2 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    border: solid black;
}

.home-testimonial {
    border: solid black;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.carousel {
    margin: 30px 30px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    border: solid   black;
}

#client-testimonial-carousel {
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: 30px 0 10px;
}


/*-----------------------------------Modal Header------------------------------*/
.modal-header {
    background-color: #181a3d;
    color: #6fc4a2;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 20px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%)!important;
}

.modal-title {
    text-align: center!important;
}

.close {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: white!important;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    opacity: 10!important;
}

.close:hover {
    color: #6fc4a2!important;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #6fc4a2!important;
    opacity: 10!important;
}

/*-----------------------------------Modal body------------------------------*/

.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #181a3d;
    color: #6fc4a2;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%)!important;    
}

.form-text {
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.btn-success {
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px!important;
    background-color: #6fc4a2!important;
    border-color: #6fc4a2!important;
}

.btn-success:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6fc4a2!important;
    border-color: #6fc4a2!important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
}

/*-------------------------------------------Bruna Page-----------------------------------*/

#bruna-image {
    border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
}

.img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #181a3d!important;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 50px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    border-radius: 30px !important;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    width: 330px!important;
}

div.card-info {
    background-color: #181a3d!important;
    border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
}

.bf-card-details {
    color: #6fc4a2!important;
}

.bf-card-job {
    color: #6fc4a2!important;
}

.card-about {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #181a3d;
    background-clip: border-box;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 50px 0 #39fd9bc9, 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%);
    border-radius: 30px!important;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    max-width: 400px; /* max-width instead of width */
    height: auto; /* height auto */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bruna Fernandes Fisioteropia | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bree+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-sm" id="navbar-color">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="assets/images/bf-logo (1).png" height="60" width="60" class="nav-img" alt=""></a>
        <!----ml-auto will push this button to the right------data toggle tells Bootstrap that it will be used as a trigger for a collapsable element on the page------------->
        <!----data-target is the ID of the collapsible element-----aria = accessible rich internet applications provides accessibility options to screen readers----->
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target ="#navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <!-----inside the span we create a class that gives us the icon, our burger button----->
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">

        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link nav-link-color" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                         
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle nav-link-color" href="services.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link-color" href="fisio.html">Fisioteropia & Pilates</a>  
                            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link-color" href="appointments.html"> Appointments</a> 
                        </div>
                </li>
            
            <li class="nav-item mr-2"><a class="nav-link nav-link-color" href="members.html">Members</a></li>

               <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle nav-link-color" href="contact.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-link-color" href="contact.html">Contact</a> 
                    </div>
                </li>            

            
            <!---Will only display on a mob device with "d-block + d-sm-none--->
            <li class="nav-item mr-auto d-block d-sm-none"> <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal" class="sign-btn"><p class="nav-link-color" class="sign-btn">Sign In / Sign Up</p></button></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block">
            <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal" class="sign-btn">Sign In / Sign Up</button>
        </div>    
    </nav>

         <!-----Modal dialogue goes here because it captures the entire screen so it needs to be a top-level element in the body---->
 <!-----A modal is described as being an island of content that sits in the middle of the page. The modal is hidden by default----->   
 <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="signUpModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Sign Up to BF Fisioteropia!</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
                            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="repeatPassword">Repeat Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="repeatPassword" placeholder="Repeat Password" required>
                        </div>
                        
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

            <main class="container-fluid">
                
                <section class="bruna-page">
                        <div class="row justify-content-around">
                            
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"class="bruna-box-1">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img src="assets/images/bruna_professional_resized.jpg" id="bruna-image" alt="Image of Bruna Fernandes">
                                    <div class="card-info">
                                        <h4 class="text-center mt-3 bf-card-details" ><b>Bruna Fernandes</b></h4>
                                        <p class="text-center bf-card-details">Physiotherapist</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" class="bruna-box-2">
                                        <div class="card-about">
                                        <h2 class="text-center mt-4">About Bruna</h2>
                                        <hr id="hr-about">
                                        <p class="text-center mt-4 mr-5 ml-5">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                                            Voluptatem eaque, saepe cumque labore asperiores accusamus quae officiis quidem. 
                                            Iusto porr o quasi placeat, natus enim rem explicabo alias quibusdam expedita provident.
                                            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium magni est optio? 
                                            Voluptates hic animi omnis sint iure quis! 
                                            Illum quod ex aperiam animi facere nobis mollitia aut dignissimos dolorum.
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                                            Voluptatem eaque, saepe cumque labore asperiores accusamus quae officiis quidem. 
                                            Iusto porr o quasi placeat, natus enim rem explicabo alias quibusdam expedita provident.
                                            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium magni est optio? 
                                            Voluptates hic animi omnis sint iure quis! 
                                            Illum quod ex aperiam animi facere nobis mollitia aut dignissimos dolorum.
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                                            Voluptatem eaque, saepe cumque labore asperiores accusamus quae officiis quidem. 
                                            </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" class="bruna-box-3">
                                Bruna-box-3
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </section>
            </main>


<footer class="footer fixed container-fluid">
      <ul class="social-networks">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i> </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i> </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i> </a>
                </li>
            </ul> 
</footer>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Ricky!
Just logged on now and I will test the changes and let you know! Thank you so much for your help!